# Swift on 10.14 without storyboard: how to redisplay window instead of creating duplicate windows?

Tags: swift

I'm working on a small Swift menu bar application for 10.14. I'm not using the storyboard feature; I'm just loading a couple informational windows through menu commands under my menu bar icon.

So when a window is loaded, if I do this:

```swift
// create changelog window object
let logWin = NSWindowController(windowNibName: "Changelog")
logWin.loadWindow()
NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
```

I get new instances of the window forever. If I instantiate my window in my class so it can be reused, once it's closed, it never displays again. I've read through posts on both Apple's developer forums as well as on SO (along with reading Apple's documentation), and I'm still unsure how to address this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know if this is the "right" way to fix my problem, but here's what I did.

This function in my ApplicationDelegate class runs when the user clicks "About..." from the menu bar icon. If the Bool `infoOpen` is `false`, load the window then put it on top. If `infoOpen` is `true`, just bring the window to the front.

```swift
@objc func showAbout() {
    if (!infoOpen) {
        // create infobox window object
        let aboutWin = NSWindowController(windowNibName: "InfoBox")
        
        aboutWin.loadWindow()
    }
    NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
}
```

The Bool `infoOpen` is handled by a `ViewController` class, which sets the Bool to `true` when the window is opened. When the window is closed, the Bool is reset to `false`.

```swift
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate {
    
    let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        toggleWindow(boolShow: true)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear() {
        self.view.window?.delegate = self
    }
    
    // triggers when window is closed
    override func viewWillDisappear() {
        toggleWindow(boolShow: false)
    }

    func toggleWindow(boolShow: Bool = false) {
        // get the window title to set the right bool
        // window title is in self.view.window.title
        let winTitle = self.view.window?.title
        
        if (winTitle?.contains("About") ?? false) {
            appDelegate.infoOpen = boolShow
        }
    }

}
```

I'm certainly open to improvements to the code. I'm not a software engineer by any stretch, just a hobbyist.